# Android Studio (AVD) log very slow, delayed (adb logcat)

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, console, android-virtual-device

I am at my wits end!  I could really use some help with Android Studio, specifically the emulator AVD.

It is outputting console logs extremely slowly.  This only just started happening, but I've backtracked through my code and rolled back to previous versions, and it is still happening.

Does anybody know what might be going on here?

What is the best way to troubleshoot slow adb logcat?

I have tried:

- Reset PC
- Clean gradle
- Invalidate/resync project
- Reset Andriod Studio
- Kill adb server, restart
- Different versions of Platform Tools/SDK BuildTools through SDK manager
- Deleting and recreating emulated device in AVD manager, increasing RAM/Storage etc. for emulator
- Rolling back my GIT project to a previous, working version

Things I haven't tried:

- Changing the build.gradle build version - I'm not familiar/confident with this, but could try it.  (i.e. SDKBuildVersion, LibVersion)
- Reinstalling windows
- Giving up (completely)

Is there anyone with more Android Studio knowledge who might have some advice on what to try here?

Thank you in advance!